# Problem with Ajax Helper in Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to implement the Ajax feature in the comments section of my blog. I have downloaded prototype-1.6.0.3.js and have placed it in the js folder inside webroot.
I have made the following changes in the layout file(default.ctp)

```
$javascript->link(array('prototype'));
```

Also, following code has been added to controllers

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Ajax','Javascript');
```

This is my code in the posts_controller.php file

```
function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Post.', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $post = $this->Post->read(null,$id);
        $comments = $this->Post->Comment->find('all',
array('conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>$id)));
        $this->set(compact('post','comments'));
    }
```

My code in view.ctp file

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<div id="comments">
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
  <div class="comment">
<p><b><?php echo $comment['Comment']['name']; ?></b></p>
      <p><?php echo $comment['Comment']['content']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $ajax->form('/comments/add','post',array('update'=>'comments'));?>
   <?php echo $form->input('Comment.name');?>
   <?php echo $form->input('Comment.content');?>
   <?php echo $form->input('Comment.post_id',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$post['Post']['id']));?>
   <?php echo $form->end('Add Comment');?>
</div>
```

I have added the following function in the comments_controller.php

```
function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Comment->create();
            if ($this->Comment->save($this->data)) {
                $comments = $this->Comment->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('post_id'=>$this->data['Comment']['post_id']),'recursive'=>-1);
                    $this->set(compact('comments'));
                    $this->render('add_success','ajax');
                    } else {
                    $this->render('add_failure','ajax');
                    }
                 }
             }
```

And following is the code in the add_success.ctp file

```
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<div class="comment">
<p><b><?php echo $comment['Comment']['name'];?></b></p>
<p><?php echo $comment['Comment']['content'];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to add comments. Nothing happens when I click on the add comments button. I have manually added comments in the databse and that works. But I am having problems when I am trying the Ajax Helper.

Where is the problem??And guys, sorry for such a long question.[:(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have firebug installed so you can test to see if it is making the ajax request?

Perhaps try doing $form->submit('Add Comment'); to generate the button and see if it makes a difference and actually performs the ajax request.

Do you get any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're following the example from ["Beginning CakePHP"](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430209775) I think I made the same error too

it's not mentioned in the book, but the name of the .js file (in webroot/js) must match the helper function argument, so do **one** of these:

1) rename prototype-1.6.0.3.js  (inside your webroot/js folder) to prototype.js

OR

2) change the helper function to

```
$javascript->link(array('prototype-1.6.0.3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you also need to include scriptaculous for the built in ajax functions to work correctly too...

Comment: Since the question was asked almost two years ago, you're probably right. CakePHP 1.3 does not require Prototype/Scriptaculous but will work with a variety of JS frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an Answer but I thought its worth mentioning that I  too ran into this problem. And Yes I am using that book mentioned by @smchacko. I am using [Prototype Version 1.7](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js):

```
//this is how I called it and renamed it to prototype
<?php echo $javascript->link( array('prototype')); ?>
```

Interestingly enough to mention that I have fire bug as well as web [Developer tool bar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/). Firebug does not return any errors but Chris Pederic's  plug-in has several warnings... Its too many to mention. This appears on the top right of your screen