# Problem with prototype framework in cake php

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

This question is somewhat related to my previous question (not necessary to go through it) 
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271625/problem-with-ajax-helper-in-cake-php)
, although this one is more of an Ajax problem.

I tested my page in firebug and I am getting the following error

**Event.Observe is not a function**

```
Event.observe('form908983160', 'submit', function(event) { new Ajax.Updater('comments','/blog/posts/comments/add', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize('form908983160'), requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'comments']}) }, false);
```

I am using the prototype framework for developing my cake php application.
How should I fix this problem?
Guys, I really need your help in this one. I am really stuck at this one. [:(]

Comment: Have you checked if prototype is loading correctly on your site? IN firebug you can easily check that by running `$('form908983160')`

Comment: @RaYell : if I remember correctly, firebug defines an $ function by itslef ; so this will work even if prototype is not loaded ; see http://getfirebug.com/commandline.html

Comment: Yes, but default implementation wont find your element and prototype's will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prototype.js has to be :

- loaded in the page *(verify it's not in 404, for instance)*
- loaded in the page before the execution of your script

Which generally means you need to include prototype.js first, and, only after that, you can include your scripts.

*As a sidenote : you are not using any other JS Framework in that page, of course...*

Comment: As I am using cake php for my application, my prototype.js file lies in the app/webroot/js folder. Moreover,I have added 
$javascript->link(array('prototype')) in default.ctp file to produce a link to the javascript file. What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that any Event.observers need to be used in global

```
 Event.observe(window,'loaded',f);
// or 
Event.observe(document,'dom:loaded',f)
```

otherwise they will not work.

For me it looks like there's problem with linking to Prototype. Open firebug and try to see the contents of your script files - if you see html, that means something went terribly wrong :-)